# Bootstrap toggle menu expand on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a navbar with dropdowns that work perfectly with hover. But on smartphones, instead of tapping to open the dropdown, I want it to open automatically as soon as the toggle menu button is tapped.

I've tried some snippets I've found around here but haven't managed to adapt any to my problem.

Comment: Can you post the code that you already have in a fiddle so that we can see what is going wrong and what you want to do?

Comment: You can find the code here (http://jsfiddle.net/fyjj67z5/). When you click on the menu, when it expands, I want the items from the dropdowns to be visible immediately.

Comment: Edited my answer.  Sorry I misread the question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just manually add the class "in" to the element with the collapse navbar-collapse classes in your markup.

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse in" role="navigation">
```

From the Bootstrap documentation on the [Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) plugin:

> Be sure to add the class collapse to the collapsible element. If you'd like it to default open, add the additional class in.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I misread the question.  Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/k89wydu0/)**.

To open the submenus, @scooterlord is correct, but the trick is that you need to use the right event.  If you try and add the open class to the elements with the dropdown class on the click event of the toggle, it won't work because the dropdowns are closed automatically when the navbar is toggled.  So, you'll have to wait until the collapse is fully shown:

```
$('.collapse.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
});
```

Comment: That only opens the menu. I also want to automatically open the dropdown-menu list items. Any ideas?

Comment: also add 'open'class to the 'dropdown' elements

Comment: that would be the solution, but how to do I specify that "open" class only applies when the site is viewed on a smartphone?

Comment: my menu is opened on page load without the html5 attributes and bootstrap classes missing. i cannot seem to close it with jquery